# How can I add the Let's Encrypt certificate to an Azure Service Definition?

Tags: azure, ssl

Whenever I enter the following XML for the certificate into the csdef:

```
<Certificate name="Let's Encrypt Authority X3"
             storeLocation="LocalMachine"
             storeName="CA"
             permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated" />
```

I get an XML validation error `The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'Let's Encrypt Authority X3' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:NamedElementNameString' - The Pattern constraint failed.`

According to the comments from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-configure-ssl-certificate) the Let's Encrypt certificate is required as it's an intermediate certificate.  But I can't package the service definition without passing XML validation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the **name** matters as long as you use the same thing in the `.cscfg`. The thumbprint is what selects the cert. Try a name without whitespace or quotes.

E.g.

#### .csdef

```xml
<Certificates>
     <Certificate name="ThisDoesNotHaveToMatchTheCertName" 
         storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
         storeName="My"
         permissionLevel="limitedOrElevated" />
```

#### .cscfg

```xml
 <Certificates>
     <Certificate name="ThisDoesNotHaveToMatchTheCertName" 
         thumbprint="9427befa18ec6865a9ebdc79d4c38de50e6316ff" 
         thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
```

Comment: It seems you're right.  The certificate worked without the apostrophe.